# How can I create a dataframe which collect the results of a for loop with multilple indexes in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I want to obtain from a for loop a dataframe in which i can visualize better the result of the code.  I'm in the context of Random survival forest, so I leave an example to explain me better.

```
library("randomForestSRC")
data(veteran, package = "randomForestSRC")
for(j in 1:3){for(i in 1:2){
  obj<- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., data = veteran, 
              ntree = 100, block.size = j, mtry=i, nodesize = 3, samptype = "swr")
  car<-1-get.cindex(obj$yvar[,1], obj$yvar[,2], obj$predicted.oob)
  print(c(car, round(i, 0), j))
}}
```

the result obtained is the following:

```
[1] 0.6748275 1.0000000 1.0000000
[1] 0.6877191 2.0000000 1.0000000
[1] 0.6577519 1.0000000 2.0000000
[1] 0.6826303 2.0000000 2.0000000
[1] 0.6614837 1.0000000 3.0000000
[1] 0.6847789 2.0000000 3.0000000
```

I want to collect this results in a dataframe, in particular i'm interested in the values of "car".

I've firstly tried only with the index j and I've obtained what i want. I have built a dataframe and car:

```
b<- (1:3)
df<-data.frame(b)
car=0
```

Then I run the same loop only for the index j and I obtain the dataframe that I want (one column that indicates j and one column for the different values obtained for car) in the subsequent way:

```
for(j in 1:3){
  obj<- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., data = veteran, 
              ntree = 100, block.size = 1, mtry=j, nodesize = 3, samptype = "swr")
  df$car[j]<-1-get.cindex(obj$yvar[,1], obj$yvar[,2], obj$predicted.oob)
}
```

The same method do not function with i and j indexes together. I hope that someone will give me sone hint to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having to deal with two indices in loops can be a bit inconvenient,
especially since you’re not after array output. It might be easier to use
`Map()` with the combinations created with `expand.grid()`. At the same time
you can swap to using more informative names:

```r
fit_car <- function(mtry, block.size) {
    obj <- rfsrc(
      Surv(time, status) ~ .,
      data = veteran,
      ntree = 100,
      block.size = block.size,
      mtry = mtry,
      nodesize = 3,
      samptype = "swr"
    )
    car <- 1 - get.cindex(obj$yvar[, 1], obj$yvar[, 2], obj$predicted.oob)
    car
}

df <- expand.grid(mtry = 1:2, block.size = 1:3)
df$car <- unlist(Map(fit_car, df$mtry, df$block.size))
df
#>   mtry block.size       car
#> 1    1          1 0.6857967
#> 2    2          1 0.7095443
#> 3    1          2 0.6437295
#> 4    2          2 0.6921294
#> 5    1          3 0.6640846
#> 6    2          3 0.6917901
```